# TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable while using requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.9

So, I was writing a program that uses the requests library. While trying to do something I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myste\Desktop\Bang.com keker\e.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(requests.get('https://www.bang.com/login_check',headers=headd,json=content).text)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 469, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

This is my code:

```
import requests
headd = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
    "Pragma":"no-cache" ,
    "Accept":"*/*" 
}
content = {
    f"\"_username\":\"MY_EMAIL\",\"_password\":\"MY_PASSWORD\",\"_remember_me\":true" 
}
print(requests.get('https://www.bang.com/login_check',headers=headd,json=content).text)
```

What this program basically does is, it will take a list of your email and passwords and then checks if they are valid. Its incase you forget your accounts password. Dont ask me what is the point of this program cuz idk myself, I got a request to make this so I am making it moyai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content is actually a `set` not a `dict`. Replace it with something like:

```
content = {"_username": "my_email", "_password": "my-password"} # etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing `content` to the `json` parameter, your passing a `set`, however, the `json` parameter is expecting a `dict`.

```
content = {
    f"\"_username\":\"MY_EMAIL\",\"_password\":\"MY_PASSWORD\",\"_remember_me\":true"
}
>>> print(type(content))
<class 'set'>
```

Instead, it should be:

```
content = {"_username": "MY_EMAIL", "_password": "MY_PASSWORD", "_remember_me": "true"}
>>> print(type(content))
<class 'dict'>
```